# How to delete everything outside of paragraph tags in Sublime Text

Tags: html, sublimetext2

This may seem odd since it's for automated upload of writing to an online content system, but here goes:

I write a story or whatever for upload in Sublime Text.  I create a Word 2010 .htm file via the Sublime Text file(export to plain text file, command line batch in Word, reopen newly-generated .htm in Sublime).  The export.htm file is a full html page, when all I need are the body entries using `<p>` tags.  For example from this export.htm:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered)">
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
    panose-1:2 11 6 3 2 2 2 2 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:10.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    line-height:115%;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
.MsoChpDefault
    {font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
.MsoPapDefault
    {margin-bottom:10.0pt;
    line-height:115%;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
-->
</style>

</head>

<body lang=EN-US>

<div class=WordSection1>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:12.0pt;text-indent:.5in'><font size=2
face="Trebuchet MS"><span style='font-size:11.0pt;line-height:115%;font-family:
"Trebuchet MS","sans-serif"'>This is a paragraph of story text to be uploaded
to the online parsing system.</span></font></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:12.0pt;text-indent:.5in'><font size=2
face="Trebuchet MS"><span style='font-size:11.0pt;line-height:115%;font-family:
"Trebuchet MS","sans-serif"'>This is a another paragraph of story text to be
uploaded to the online parsing system.</span></font></p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The only part I want to keep is as follows:

```
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:12.0pt;text-indent:.5in'><font size=2
face="Trebuchet MS"><span style='font-size:11.0pt;line-height:115%;font-family:
"Trebuchet MS","sans-serif"'>This is a paragraph of story text to be uploaded
to the online parsing system.</span></font></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:12.0pt;text-indent:.5in'><font size=2
face="Trebuchet MS"><span style='font-size:11.0pt;line-height:115%;font-family:
"Trebuchet MS","sans-serif"'>This is a another paragraph of story text to be
uploaded to the online parsing system.</span></font></p>
```

Once I have this specific part of the file I can perform one more automated action (join lines) and the file is ready to be sent to the online parser.

The parser needs some kind of html text formatting, but only accepts content for the body of the page (the rest of the page is automated via the submission system.)  This requires an html export from a word processor, but all known processors spit out max-width html.  The parser sees the newline in the file (html would ignore newlines) and adds 
 tags, so this is why I need to run my sublime script to join lines in the exported file.  But to do that I need to clean up the export so only the desired lines (content paragraphs) are present, or else general html will get woven into the single line uploaded to the parser.

I realize the best solution here might be to change the parser so it ignores the unused junk of the file, but it's controlled by an uncompromising third party (it's a creative story hosting site).  Anyway, that's off target.  I can handle that myself, and just need to clean out non-paragraph sections from the file to do so.

I have found ways to select a single tag manually and then grab the whole of its contents, but grabbing all of one type or grabbing the inverse (as requested here, all EXCEPT the desired tags) is out of my reach.  I've searched Google high and low as well as here on stackoverflow and come up dry.

Any help is appreciated, guys.

Comment: If all you're doing is wrapping some text in HTML tags, why don't you create a program to do just that?

Comment: Since you already have a way to grab a single tag and it's contents, have you tried following the same actions while leveraging the multiple cursors within ST?

Comment: Good God, Word is still using `<font>` tags?

Comment: Sadly yes, Word still outputs some pretty atrocious HTML.  However for whatever reason the site I upload content to requires it for any font styling, recessed indents, or basic block formatting.  Also I currently DON'T have a method to select the tags I require.  that's my issue.  I need the text prior to the first '<p>' tag and the text following the very last '</p>' tag to be isolated and deleted.  However multiple cursors might be able to select all of the individual paragraph sections and join them.  I'll experiment with that if it's even possible, maybe to then dump to a new file.

Answer (score -2):

Select the text you want to delete by holding down the "shift" key and pressing the "arrow" keys. Then press the "backspace" key.